# CSS background-image will not show up

Tags: html, css, sass, background, background-image

I am looking to create a header with a logo link that changes color upon hover. For this reason I want to use the "background-image" property instead of simply using an img tag in the HTML. I am trying to enter my logo in the background image URL inside of div.logo but for some reason it is not appearing. I have tried entering the path in multiple different ways. Most recently, I uploaded the picture online and tried using the hosting URL (seen in code below) but not even this is working. Can anyone help me out?

HTML

```
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="logo"></div>
      <nav>
        <a href="#" title="User"><%= image_tag("new-user-icon.png", class: "user-icon") %></a>
        <a href="#" title="About"><%= image_tag("about-icon.png", class: "about-icon") %></a>
        <a href="#" title="Contact"><%= image_tag("contact-icon.png", class: "contact-icon") %></a>
        <a href="#" title="Main Menu" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <div class="dropdown" >
          <%=image_tag("new-menu-icon.png", class: "menu-icon") %>
        </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Assets</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Debts</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Incomes</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Expenses</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Transfers</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Account</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Log Out</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
    ...
  </body>
```

CSS (Sass)

```
header{
  display:inline-block;
  background: rgb(125,185,232);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(125,185,232,1) 0%, 
  rgba(32,124,202,1) 0%, rgba(32,124,202,1) 0%, rgba(98,189,234,1) 0%, 
  rgba(129,202,237,1) 50%, rgba(98,189,234,1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(125,185,232,1) 0%,rgba(32,124,202,1) 0%,rgba(32,124,202,1) 0%,rgba(98,189,234,1) 0%,rgba(129,202,237,1) 50%,rgba(98,189,234,1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(125,185,232,1) 0%,rgba(32,124,202,1) 0%,rgba(32,124,202,1) 0%,rgba(98,189,234,1) 0%,rgba(129,202,237,1) 50%,rgba(98,189,234,1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( 
  startColorstr='#7db9e8', endColorstr='#62bdea',GradientType=1 );
  border-bottom: 1px solid $universal-background;
  height: 55px;
  width: 100%;
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
  div.logo{
    float: left;
    height: 55px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url('https://image.ibb.co/nw64yw/logo_white.png');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The problem

Your basic problem is that the background-image ignores the dimensions of the container. Since your image file is very big, you can not see anything of it because it is only showing the transparent upper-left corner.  Also there are some styles missing which you need to apply to show the background-image appropriate.

#### What do you need to do?

1. `background-position: center` This makes sure that the background-image will be placed centered inside the container.
2. `background-size: contain` This specifies the size of the background images. This property arrived with CSS3 and solved a lot of problems with background images. Your are able to add pixel values or `contain` / `cover`. `Contain` scales the image to the largest size to fit inside the container. `Cover` scales the image to the largest size to cover the whole container. [W3C reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)
3. `background-repeat: no-repeat` We only wont to show the image once (obvious).

#### Code snippet separate properties:

```
.logo { 
  background-size: contain;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-image: url('https://image.ibb.co/nw64yw/logo_white.png');
}
```

#### Code snippet with shorthand: ([W3C reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp))

```
.logo { 
  background-size: contain;
  background-image: transparent url('path_to_image.png') center no-repeat;
}
```

> [Live jsFiddle example can be found here](https://jsfiddle.net/e9jqknf8/)

I hope that helps you to understand what went wrong. If you have any additional questions, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Add this CSS

```
div.logo {
    float: left;
    height: 55px;
    width: 140px;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url(https://image.ibb.co/nw64yw/logo_white.png);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 13px;
}
```